# IIS 8 AppPool using excessive resources, how to find the culprit?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, iis, umbraco

At my workplace, we've been busy for days to keep a .NET web-application (Umbraco based) with a pretty huge database up and running. We've done pretty much every possible trick in the book to get resource-usage down, but it's not working at all.

It's a pretty busy site, and the live website is suffering from severe performance issues. We initially had the site running on Azure with upscaling and that seemed alright (still sluggish), but due to Umbraco not being able to handle multiple instance on Azure properly* and lots of hours fixing those things, we were forced to move it to single non-azure dedicated server instead.

With 6 cores and 12GB of memory, the site is still going beserk when the site is really active (lets say 100 requests per minute).

**The cry for help:** Could anyone assist in how we can determine what is causing this, cause we're really running out of ideas and just want to know what the site is doing thats draining so much CPU and why its stocking up close to 2GB of memory.

When the site is not as active, say midnight, it performs ok, so it really seems like IIS can't handle that much requests (which seems unlikely to me, but okay). Are there any tricks that we don't know off? Can we separate the app-pool in multiple handlers, or something?

*We we're unsure this was Azure's doing or Umbraco's, we went through the source and it seems to be locking files and threads properly, but we still ended up with lots of issues where instances clashed with eachother.

Comment: This may be related to some inefficient code or memory management - there is a lot of things you can start from. So many that it would be article, not an answer. For example, have you looked at your site under performance counters from group .NET CLR Memory and .NET Exceptions? Have you analyzed memory dump taken from PRD under heavy load? Have you load test your application on some test/quality environment to profile it with tools like jetBrains dotTrace or ANTS Profiler?

Comment: There is not a lot of custom code in the site at all - a few things related to Twitter and that's it. We've all been through it, it's not doing anything weird and everything that can be disposed or cleaned up, is cleaned up. We also went through all Razor views, again, not doing really interesting stuff, queries generated are OK too. Could you elaborate on analyzing the memory dump - I guess you mean a Performance Monitor dump? This is the first time we've seen something like this happen so we never ever had to resort to that because profiling was usually enough to catch it.

Comment: Memory dump and Performance Monitor analysis are different things, you could take separately. You can try to use .NET Memory Profiler tool to open you dump, taken with procdump for example. Try also [Performance Analysis of Logs (PAL) Tool](https://pal.codeplex.com/)

Comment: We got a lot closer, apparently Umbraco was doing really weird stuff with our Razor-pages under the hood which were not unlike anything we've done before for equally sized websites.

Comment: I've experienced a similar situation: Load times and performance monitoring was all ok in development and test environments with no load, but when we load tested the site with loadimpact.com, we started seeing some *really* nasty spikes in load time, when the number of active users increased above 60-ish (experimental test results on an azure website was better, but far from good). We isolated the bottleneck to some content queries, but none of the dev's could really make any sense of it - the queries didn't seem complex at all. We ended up caching a lot of data in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very broad question but in my experience with umbraco, the biggest perfomance I saw is after caching partial views. Here is my implementation:

```
public static class CachedPartialExtensions
{
    public static IHtmlString MyCachedPartial(
                        this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,
                        string partialViewName,
                        object model,
                        int seconds,
                        bool cacheByPage = false)
    {

        var cacheKey = "fpc-";  //prefix to know which keys to clear on page publish 
        cacheKey += cacheByPage ? "page-" + UmbracoContext.Current.PageId : "global";
        cacheKey += partialViewName;

        var partial = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] as MvcHtmlString;
        if (partial == null)
        {
            partial = htmlHelper.Partial(partialViewName, model);
            if(partial != null)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Cache.Add(cacheKey, partial, null,
                    DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(seconds), Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
            }
        }
        return partial;
    }

    public static DateTime Hours(this int hours)
    {
        return DateTime.Now.AddHours(hours);
    }
}
```

For example if the menu is the same for every page you would call

```
@Html.MyCachedPartial("Global/_Menu", Model, 24.Hours())
```

And if you have page specific partial views you would call

```
@Html.MyCachedPartial("Global/_PageLeftMenu", Model, 24.Hours(), cacheByPage: true)
```

We cache for 24 hours or on publish/unpublish events:

```
public class MyApplicationEventHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarted(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        ContentService.Published += ContentServicePublished;
        ContentService.UnPublished += ContentService_UnPublished;
    }

    void ContentService_UnPublished(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> e)
    {
        ClearCache(e.PublishedEntities);
    }

    private void ContentServicePublished(IPublishingStrategy sender, PublishEventArgs<IContent> args)
    {
        ClearCache(args.PublishedEntities);
    }

    private void ClearCache(IEnumerable<IContent> nodes)
    {
        var cacheKeys = ((IEnumerable)HttpContext.Current.Cache).Cast<DictionaryEntry>()
                                                                .Select(de => de.Key.ToString())
                                                                .ToList();

        var cacheKeysToClear = cacheKeys.Where(key => key.StartsWith("fpc-global")).ToList(); 
        foreach (var node in nodes)
        {
            cacheKeysToClear.AddRange(cacheKeys.Where(key => key.StartsWith("fpc-page-" + node.Id)));
        }

        cacheKeysToClear.ForEach(key => HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(key)); 
    }
}
```

After this we saw dramatic boost of performance on the frontend as well as a dramatic decrease on the CPU usage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll accept this since its a useful explanation. Caching is very important! In regards to my original question: we ran it through RedGates profiler for a good day long and at some point started seeing points a page would consume up to 200MB. We fixed those and just kept on profiling till we found all culprits. Our designers know their way around Razor but weren't aware of a few tricks to prevent excessive data-usage as happened.